# Unable to check app(creatde with appMobi) on device

Tags: appmobi

I have created mobile app using appMobi XDK.

Its working fine if I test locally (returning data from webservices.)

But when i'm trying to test on device, * unable to get the latest app * and not getting any response from service end.(tried with both options "test anywhere" and "test on local wifi")

( * its showing the only part which is done at the first time when i checked on device, after that i did lot of modifications in app but unable to see any change on device * )

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: got the solution..here it is  [link]http://forums.appmobi.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=892

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you did a push to cloud?  Also, you'll get better support at http://forums.appmobi.com

As to the post below, the default index.html has a reference to xhr.js , as long as that is in place, you do not have to worry about cross domain scripting issues.  We wrap the calls to the XMLHttpRequest object to our native calls.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a cross-domain scripting permission issue. AppMobi provides a getremotedata call to get around this or they have a wrapper library called xhr.js - are you using either one of those?